# Objects scraped from web are character "empty" in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, get, screen-scraping, httr

I'm sorry to ask this question once again: I know a lot of people have asked this before, but even looking at the answers they received I still can't solve my problem.

The code I'm using was actually inspired on some of the answers I was able to find:

```
link <- "https://letterboxd.com/alexissrey/activity/"
page <- link %>% GET(config = httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE))%>% read_html
```

Until this point everything seems to be working ok, but then I try to run the following line...

```
names <- link %>% html_nodes(".prettify > a") %>% html_text()
```

... to download all the movie names in that page, but the objet I get is empty.

It is worth mentioning that I've tried the same code for other pages (specially the ones mentioned by other users in their questions) and it worked perfectly.

So, can anyone see what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can get the film link and name by using `RSelenium`

Start the browser

```
url = 'https://letterboxd.com/alexissrey/activity/'
library(RSelenium)
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)
```

Get links to film by

```
  remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
    read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="SentimentContainer"]/div[1]/div[1]') %>% 
    html_text()

 [1] "/film/the-power-of-the-dog/"                     "/nachotorresok/film/dune-2021/"                  "/furquerita/film/the-princess-switch/"          
 [4] "/film/fosse-verdon/"                             "/film/the-greatest-showman/"                     "/film/misery/"                                  
 [7] "/film/when-harry-met-sally/"                     "/film/stand-by-me/"                              "/film/things-to-come-2016/"                     
[10] "/film/bergman-island-2021/"                      "/film/king-lear-2018/"                           "/film/21-grams/"                                
[13] "/film/the-house-that-jack-built-2018/"           "/film/dogville/"                                 "/film/all-that-jazz/"                           
[16] "/alexissrey/list/peliculas-para-ver-en-omnibus/" "/film/in-the-mouth-of-madness/"
```

Get movie names by,

```
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes('.target') %>%  
  html_text()
 [1] "The Power of the Dog"                 " ★★★½  review of Dune"                " ★★★½  review of The Princess Switch"
 [4] "Fosse/Verdon"                         "The Greatest Showman"                 "Misery"                              
 [7] "When Harry Met Sally..."              "Stand by Me"                          "Things to Come"                      
[10] "Bergman Island"                       "King Lear"                            "21 Grams"                            
[13] "The House That Jack Built"            "Dogville"                             "All That Jazz"                       
[16] "Películas para ver en ómnibus"        "In the Mouth of Madness"
```